# Como alinhar verticalmente e horizontalmente elemento dentro de uma row no Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Estou tendo um problema enorma para centralizar um texto embaixo de uma imagem no Bootstrap. Já tentei de tudo, com position, table-cell.

```css
.bloco-materia {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transition-property: box-shadow,transform;
    transition-duration: 400ms;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.16,1,.29,.99);

}

.bloco-materia:hover  {
    filter: saturate(1.5);
    transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
    box-shadow: 0 12px 30px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    transition-property: box-shadow,transform;
    transition-duration: 600ms;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.16,1,.29,.99);
}

.bloco-materia img{
  height: 80px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.bloco-materia:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.bloco-materia:hover  h1 {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  opacity: 1;
}

.bloco-materia img, .bloco-materia h1 {
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 600ms;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.16,1,.29,.99);
}

.bloco-materia h1 {
  font-family: 'SegoeUI', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.6;
  height: 95px;
  display:table-cell; 
  vertical-align:middle;

}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#">
    <div class="bloco-materia" style="background: #b26a00">
     <img src="#">
     <h1>Texto</h1>
    </div>
    </a>
   </div>
      
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#">
    <div class="bloco-materia" style="background: #357a38">
     <img src="../assets/images/materias/ciencias-natureza.png">
     <h1>Ciências da Natureza e suas Tecnologias</h1>
    </div>
    </a>    
   </div>
```

Qual a melhor forma de centralizar verticalmente e horizontalmente o texto, para se adaptar tanto a textos com 2 linhas, quanto com 3, ou com uma só (como Redação)?

Comment: Qual versão do Bootstrap?

Comment: 3.3.5. Esqueci de comentar. Na 4 eu consigo tranquilo, mas estou mexendo na 3.3.5 num projeto antigo e tenho que me adequar..

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, use a tag `<center><h1>Texto</h1></center>`
Ela vai centralizar exatamente no centro

Comment: Ou a classe text-center do bootstrap.

Comment: E na vertical como fica? Ele não quer só na horizontal pelo que eu entendi

Comment: Ai ele usa um sistema de grid, e seleciona as colunas nos lugares desejados.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Posta um exemplo ai pra ajuda seu colega, sua resposta está muito incompleta e não responde a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize os atributos da funcionalidade de layout 'grid' do bootstrap: https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.5/docs/examples/grid/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="bloco-materia" style="background: #b26a00">
          <img src="#">
            <h1 class="text-center">Texto</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="bloco-materia" style="background: #357a38">
           <img src="../assets/images/materias/ciencias-natureza.png">
             <h1 class="text-center">Ciências da Natureza e suas Tecnologias</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Estou usando a versão 3.3.5 e não possui o justify-content-center

Comment: Atualizei o exemplo para a versão apropriada

Answer (score 0):

Tenta o vertical alignment do bootstrap link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/vertical-align/

ou na div `'pai'` você coloca no `css = align-itens: center;` ai ele alinha todos os `'filhos'` verticalmente

ou na `tag` que você quer alinhar coloca o `css = align-self: center;` ai a própria `tag` se alinha ao centro.

Mas claro tudo isso dentro de uma `div` com o `css de display: flex;` para poder usar o `flex-box`